# before loading a component in angular2 call the API with dynamic ID

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have a **company.component.ts** and **company.component.html**

I have a **companyDeatials.component.ts** and **companyDeatials.html**



**company.component.html**

```
<div class="container">

  <div *ngFor = "let company of companies" >
      <div class="card card-1 " id="wrapper" routerLink='/company-detail/{{company["_id"]}}' > 
          <label class="center"> 
              {{company["comapny_name"]}} 
         </label> 
    </div>

  </div>
```

- when I click in  **..div class="card card-1...**  it load the new
  component **routerLink='/company-detail/{{company["_id"]}}'** where
  id is dynamic.

---

- I want whenever the user clicks on **..div class="card card-1...** I
  want to call the **GET API to "/api/company/{{company["_id"]}}"** and
  load this 
  **companyDeatials.component.ts** with response of GET method
- how do i achive this. Its like passing the ID from
  **company.component.html** to **companyDeatials.component.ts** and do the api call then load the **companyDeatials.component.ts**.